# How to list alphabetically by name and then by most recent SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to order my table first BY name alphabetically and then within the name the date must be most recent first

Here is what I've tried:

```
select ME_BORROWER.ABN_BOR_NO, ME_BORROWER.ABN_BOR_NAME, ABN_ACCESS_NO, ABN_LOAN_DATE
from ME_BORROWER LEFT OUTER JOIN ME_LOAN ON
ME_BORROWER.ABN_BOR_NO = ME_LOAN.ABN_BOR_NO
where ABN_TOWN='Leicester' or ABN_TOWN='Hinkley'
GROUP BY ME_BORROWER.ABN_BOR_NAME
ORDER BY ABN_LOAN_DATE asc;
```

Comment: Hint:  `ORDER BY ABN_BOR_NAME, ABN_LOAN_DATE DESC`.

Comment: That GROUP BY looks strange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
ORDER BY ABN_BOR_NAME ASC, ABN_LOAN_DATE DESC
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! been awake working on my coursework for hours my mind went blanl and relly needed this last piece. Ill answer correct when overflow lets me in 10mins !!!!! thanks you

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
select P17192142_BORROWER.ABN_BOR_NO, P17192142_BORROWER.ABN_BOR_NAME, ABN_ACCESS_NO, ABN_LOAN_DATE
    from P17192142_BORROWER LEFT OUTER JOIN P17192142_LOAN ON
    P17192142_BORROWER.ABN_BOR_NO = P17192142_LOAN.ABN_BOR_NO
    where ABN_TOWN='Leicester' or ABN_TOWN='Hinkley'
    ORDER BY ABN_BOR_NAME, ABN_LOAN_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query would be clearer with table aliases and the `in` operator:

```
select b.ABN_BOR_NO, b.ABN_BOR_NAME, l.ABN_ACCESS_NO, l.ABN_LOAN_DATE
from P17192142_BORROWER b LEFT OUTER JOIN
     P17192142_LOAN l
     ON b.ABN_BOR_NO = l.ABN_BOR_NO
where b.ABN_TOWN in ('Leicester', 'Hinkley')
order by b.ABN_BOR_NAME, l.ABN_LOAN_DATE desc;
```

The `GROUP BY` seems unnecessary.